# TypeScript: type for partial function arguments

Tags: typescript, function, arguments, typescript-generics, optional-parameters

I'm looking for some kind of *"subset of function arguments"-type* `PartialFunction<fn>`.

The function `run` accepts a single argument, which is a function that is guaranteed to be called with 2 arguments (`number` and `string`).

Now I wanted to create a type for a function that accepts the same order of arguments, but make them optional:

```
type MyFunction = (a: number, b: string) => string | undefined
type OtherFunction = PartialFunction<MyFunction>
// which then can be one of:
//     (a: number, b: string) => string | undefined
//     (a: number) => string | undefined
//     () => string | undefined
```

But maybe my problem can be solved a different way. So here's the code:

```
type MyFunction = (a: number, b: string) => string | undefined;

const run = (execFn: MyFunction) => {
    const result = execFn(42, "abc");
}

// here MyFunction can't be used for typing, because function argument b is missing
const log = (a: number): undefined => {
    console.log(a);
    return undefined;
}

// here MyFunction is valid, because a and b are present
const compare = (v?: number): MyFunction => (a, b) => {
    log(a);
    return v === a ? b : "";
}

run(log)
run(compare(42))
```

Basically I want to express that `const log` is *"compatible"* with `MyFunction`, using something like this:

```
const log: CompatibleWith<MyFunction> = (a) => {
    console.log(a);
    return undefined;
}
```

Is this somehow possible? Or is there some better solution to my problem?

Comment: would you consider a solution that turns the arguments into an object with multiple keys? i.e. `run({ a: 5, b: "foo" })`

Comment: @szaman That sounds like a reasonable way to go if that solves the problem

Comment: You should know that a union of functions, when called acts like an intersection of functions, and vice versa. So do you really want a union of functions there? That would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo5LLN).

Comment: If you want to do something like "compatible with", then TS 4.9+ introduces the new `satisfies` operator that basically does this: https://tsplay.dev/mqkKJw

Comment: @caTS has the right answer. Consider making it an answer?

Comment: @caTS Looks interesting, but it seems like I still have to type my function by hand. If possible I'd like to omit the explicit `(a: number)` typing.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't possible, even with just an explicit type annotation (`const thing: ... = (a) => ...`). Frankly, `satisfies` is the closest thing you're gonna get to "compatible with". An explicit type annotation loses the original typing of the function, but `satisfies` merely checks if the value *satisfies* the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first create a type to get our parameters:

```
type AllLess<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> =
    T extends readonly [...infer Head, any]
        ? AllLess<Head> | T
        : T;
```

This type (with the lack of a better name) simply gives us a union of all the tuples "under" this one:

```
type T = AllLess<[1, 2, 3]>; // [1, 2, 3] | [1, 2] | [1] | []
```

Then your PartialFunction type could be implemented as:

```
type PartialFunction<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    AllLess<Parameters<F>> extends infer P extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>
        ? P extends P ? (...args: P) => ReturnType<F> : never
        : never;
```

[Distributing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over the parameters we got from the previous type, we then get our union of functions, as desired. It is important to note that *attempting to call a function of this type acts as if you are calling an intersection of functions instead*. Meaning:

```
const fn: ((a: number) => void) | ((a: string) => void) = ...

// `fn` has type `(a: number & string) => void`...
// 'number & string' is 'never'...
fn(""); // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

Fortunately, in the next version of TypeScript (4.9), we'll get the much wanted [`satisfies`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator) operator. It's the kind of thing that you don't know you want until you want it :)

```
const log = ((a: number) => {
    console.log(a);
    return undefined;
}) satisfies PartialFunction<MyFunction>;
```

Now, it isn't explicitly typed as `PartialFunction<MyFunction>`, but we can sleep easy knowing that `log` is now being checked if it is assignable to `PartialFunction<MyFunction>`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqkKJw)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) to make your function accept an object and use the keys as different arguments. Then you can use the built-in [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) type to construct a type where each argument is optional.

I think the most readable way to achieve this is to first define a generic function, which can take any type as properties. For your original function, you would define it with a type `GenericFunction<Props>`, while for your "partial function" you would use `GenericFunction<Partial<Props>>`, like this:

```
type GenericFunction<PropsType> = (props: PropsType) => string | undefined;

type Props = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
};
type MyFunction = GenericFunction<Props>;
type OtherFunction = GenericFunction<Partial<Props>>;
```

Now you can use your definition to type the functions used in your example. You will just need to rewrite the call signature to accept an object.

```
const run = (execFn: OtherFunction) => {
    const result = execFn({a: 42, b: "abc"});
}

const log: OtherFunction = ({ a }) => {
    console.log(a);
    return undefined;
}

const compare = (v?: number): OtherFunction => ({a, b}) => {
    log({ a });
    return v === a ? b : "";
}
```

Check out the working example in the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgMQK7zcFA9vADwAKSBYAzgCrgQB8UAvFABRgXUBcU5ltegEoWTKsFTwA5lAA+UHABMIAMxSJFAbgBQ20JD5cqLKAG9tUKAENe8LAFsARsh2XHvcZKk6Avjv3QALIg2Lj4RCZwiKiYOHiEJPzUDP70UADywAAWyKHxEaxRyOh54YlWSPhWADZkRgwpumhE4lBIOCZsEAAeEJjwvJk5SKUJIsxM5paWzfCtSBBUWNXAJj19GPBspjZQACwATAA0UO5QAERWjmjnPkK+TS2r1QRSg9m5cWWdptZQd6IzBZprMqARqhAAHQvKRsKz3YGWBbALBIeAKeDKNQaB7aUGrZr2MAVaCsNgANwA-LYHM4kEJ3sNRgUmNsrCdHACJkDplAYds-ndXNNkaj0eSWMxWFYoJTTlBeOdzrj2lsYUJtKq2ITiQs2IchEIgA).

Comment: The solution has an issue: You can also call `log({ b })` (without `a`)